# Angular component not re-rendering when property triggered from with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular Component (im using v1.5.6) which listens for the device orientation and then shows a message if the user is using a tablet and have turned to portrait mode (the checks for this are working correctly). My template is:

```
<div ng-show="$crtl.isTablet" class="orientation-warning-message tablet-warning-message">
    <p>We think you are accessing this app on a tablet - you must use the app in landscape mode to continue (turn on side)</p>
</div>
```

and my component:

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .component('checkDevice', {
    templateUrl: 'directives/checkDevice/checkDevice.tpl.html',
    controller: function() {
      var self = this;

      this.isTablet = false;

      window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {

        // do some checks here and if a tablet and on portrait mode then:
        self.isTablet = true;

      }, false);

    }
});
```

But the message does not show because setting `isTablet` from within the `addEventListener` callback does not appear to re-render the component. If I set `isTablet` to `true` outside of the `addEventListener` callback, then it works. Do I need to manually trigger a component re-render somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to add a $scope.$apply() ...like:

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .component('checkDevice', {
    templateUrl: 'directives/checkDevice/checkDevice.tpl.html',
    controller: function(scope) {
      var self = this;

      this.isTablet = false;

      window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {


        // do some checks here and if a tablet and on portrait mode then:
    scope.$apply(function(){     
       self.isTablet = true;
    });
      }, false);

    }
});
```

Cause Angular don't see external events (like SetTimeOut()) you have to force it to refresh your scope